# Función para eliminar registro

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy trabajando con PHP, tengo una lista con información de solicitudes. En esta lista muestro id, nombre de servicio y las opciones de editar y eliminar. Lo que estoy intentando hacer es que al presionar eliminar, se despliegue un cuadro en donde me pregunte su deseo eliminar el registro. Tengo una función para el botón eliminar, que al ser presionado debería enviar el ID del registro a otra pagina PHP y en ese momento ejecutar la Query para cambiar el estado de 1 a 0 y con eso eliminar de la lista.

El mensaje de confirmación se despliega correctamente, pero no elimina el registro ni tampoco hay modificacion en la base de datos, al parecer hay un problema con el envío de los parámetros, les comparto mi código para que por favor me puedan indicar que estoy haciendo mal.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### MI LISTA

```
 <form id="form1">
  <table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Nombre Típo de Práctica</th>
        <th>Acciones</th>
    </tr>
    <?php 

    $query = mysqli_query($conection,"SELECT * FROM tipo WHERE estatus = 1");
    mysqli_close($conection);

    $result = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($result > 0)
    {
        while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) 
        {   
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $data["id"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $data["nombre"]; ?></td>
            <td>
                <a href="editar.php?id=<?php echo $data["id"]; ?>">Editar</a>
                <button type="button" onclick = "delete_practica(event)"> Eliminar</button>
    <?php 
        } 
    ?>  
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php 
    }
    ?>
  </table>
  </form>
```

#### MI FUNCION

```
<script>
  function delete_practica(e)
  {
    var res = confirm("Esta seguro?");
    if(res == false)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    else
    {
        var frm = document.getElementById('form1');
        var data = new FormData(frm);
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("POST", "delete.php", true);
        xhttp.send(data);
        $('#form1').trigger('reset');
    }
  }
 </script>
```

#### PAGINA DELETE.PHP

```
 include('../conexion.php');

 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
 {
    $id = $con->real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['id']));

    $ins = $con->query("UPDATE tipo SET estatus = 0 WHERE id = $id");

    if ($ins) 
    {
     echo 'ARCHIVO ELIMINADO EXITOSAMENTE';
    } 
    else 
    {
      echo 'ERROR';
    }
 } 
 else 
 {
   echo 'ERROR';
 }
```

Comment: "Por ahora no he logrado que al presionar elimine el registro" no se ejecuta el boton? no envia los parametros? no va a la otra pagina? esa frase, no nos da un indicio de tu problema en particular.. podes aclarar mejor el problema?

Comment: gracias, pregunta actualizada.

Comment: Te fijaste si cambia en la base de datos?

Comment: No hay cambios en la base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un formulario y dentro solo la tabla con información, sin campos ni botones que lo procesen (tipo submit), por eso es que no se envían datos. No es necesario tener formularios para ejecutar peticiones AJAX, basta con obtener los datos y enviarlos.

```
<!-- Sin formulario, solo la tabla -->
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Nombre Típo de Práctica</th>
        <th>Acciones</th>
    </tr>
    <?php 

    $query = mysqli_query($conection,"SELECT * FROM tipo WHERE estatus = 1");
    mysqli_close($conection);

    $result = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($result > 0)
    {
        while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) 
        {   
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $data["id"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $data["nombre"]; ?></td>
            <td>
                <a href="editar.php?id=<?php echo $data["id"]; ?>">Editar</a>
                <button type="button" onclick = "delete_practica(event)"> Eliminar</button>
    <?php 
        } 
    ?>  
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php 
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

En Javascript usas el evento para saber dónde se hizo el clic y buscar desde ahí ID del usuario, accediendo primero a la fila (tr) y obteniendo ID por el contenido de la primera celda:

```
<script>
function delete_practica(e) {
    let res = confirm("¿Esta seguro?");
    if(!res) {
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        // Obtener botón desde el evento
        let button = e.target;
        // Fila a la que pertenece el botón
        let tr = button.closest('tr');
        // ID es el texto de la primera celda
        let id = tr.cells[1].textContent;

        // Creas el objeto FormData
        let data = new FormData();
        // Agregas ID (nombre de campo y valor)
        data.append('id', id);

        // Inicializas y ejecutas petición AJAX
        let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("POST", "delete.php", true);
        xhttp.send(data);
    }
}
</script>
```

Puedes obtener ID en una sola línea, pero lo dejé por partes para que entiendas lo que hace cada cosa.

```
let id = e.target.closest('tr').cells[1].textContent;
```

Esta línea: `$('#form1').trigger('reset');` es de jQuery y te sugiero investigar cómo hacer las peticiones AJAX con esa librería o usar solo Javascript puro.

Además, no estás obteniendo la respuesta del servidor, por lo que no sabes qué debes hacer a continuación y, en caso de haber borrado el registro correctamente, también deberías eliminar la fila de la tabla.

Puedes obtener la respuesta del servidor con el evento [onreadystatechange](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readystatechange_event) o, mejor aún, realizar las peticiones con la [API fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. Ejecute el código pero aun no elimina el registro, no modifica la base de datos. Al pasar directamente el parámetro a la pagina delete.php, elimina el registro pero a través de la función aun no es posible.

Comment: @SBK22, revisa la consola del navegador después de intentar eliminar un registro. ¿Aparece algún error? Si es así, por favor edita tu pregunta para agregarlo.

Comment: No muestra ningún error